# How can I get a hold of the argument of an asynchronous callback 'onResponse'?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, callback, apollo

I'm implementing a GraphQL client in a Java application using Apollo's auto generation of queries, and so far I've been able to chain calls and I also get the data I want. The issue is that Apollo makes me implement the anonymous method `ApolloCall.Callback<>()` which overrides `void onResponse(Response response)` and `void onFailure()`, but I'm unable to find a way to get a hold of this `Response` object, which I want to collect and make sure I have.

This is a Spring Boot project on Java 11, I've tried to make use of `CompletableFuture` but with limited knowledge of it and how to use it for this particular problem I feel out of luck. I've also tried to implement the RxJava support that Apollo is supposed to have but I couldn't resolve dependency issues with that approach.

I'm pretty sure that futures will solve it but again I don't know how.

```java
  public void getOwnerIdFromClient() {
    client
        .query(getOwnerDbIdQuery)
        .enqueue(
            new ApolloCall.Callback<>() {
              @Override
              public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response<Optional<GetOwnerDbIdQuery.Data>> response) {
                int ownerId =
                    response
                        .data()
                        .get()
                        .entities()
                        .get()
                        .edges()
                        .get()
                        .get(0)
                        .node()
                        .get()
                        .ownerDbId()
                        .get();

                System.out.println("OwnerId = " + ownerId);
              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(@Nonnull ApolloException e) {
                logger.error("Could not retrieve response from GetOwnerDbIdQuery.", e);
              }
            });
  }
```

Since I wish to work with this `int ownerId` outside of the `onResponse` this isn't a sufficient solution. I'd actually like to make this call x amount of times, and create a list of all the id's I actually got, since this might return a null id as well, which means I need some way to wait for them all to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, this can be done using Futures:

- change return type to Future
- complete the future in onResponse

Approximately:

```
public Future<Integer> getOwnerIdFromClient(){
    Future<Integer> result=new CompletableFuture<Integer>();

    client
    .query(getOwnerDbIdQuery)
    .enqueue(
    new ApolloCall.Callback<>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response<Optional<GetOwnerDbIdQuery.Data>>response){
                // get owner Id
                System.out.println("OwnerId = "+ownerId);
                result.complete(ownerId)
                }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@Nonnull ApolloException e){
                logger.error("Could not retrieve response from GetOwnerDbIdQuery.",e);result.completeExceptionally(e);


                }
        });

    return result;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is coming across this, it took me quite a while to figure out the generics, but you can do this in a generic manner (to avoid the copy/paste for all your different query types) by using the following function as a separate class or wrapper:

```
    private <D extends Operation.Data, T, V extends Operation.Variables> CompletableFuture<T> execute(Query<D, T, V> query) {
    CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    client.query(query).enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Response<T> response) {
            if (response.hasErrors()) {
                String errors = Objects.requireNonNull(response.getErrors()).stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
                future.completeExceptionally(new ApolloException(errors));
                return;
            }
            future.complete(response.getData());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull ApolloException e) {
            future.completeExceptionally(e);
        }
    });

    return future;
}
```

Then it should just be a case of calling

```
Integer myResult = execute(getOwnerDbIdQuery).get();
```